# Connecting a method of an imported class with a class of the main script

Tags: python, oop, architecture, tkinter

I couldn't search for these problem because I don't know the key word to use, therefore if it is duplicate or answered elsewhere, please let me know.

I have a file which creates the main window with tkinter, and import some other modules with different functions and classes. I want a method of a class to output something into a tkinter widget I create. How can I do it?

file1.py:

```
from tkinter import * # I use python 3
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from file2 import *

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.output_text = tkst.ScrolledText(self, width = 100, height = 20,
                                wrap = WORD, bd=0)
        self.output_text.grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky="nsew")

root = Tk()
root.title("Game")
app = Application(root)
center(root)
root.mainloop()
```

file2.py:

```
class Hero(object):
    def attack(self, enemy, damage):
        Hero.hits+=1
        if self.hits==0:
            attack = "{}, attacks our enemy {}. Producing {} points of damage.\n".format(
                      self.__name, enemy.creature, truncate(damage))
            # I use code like this in the Application definition.
            app.output_text.insert(END, attack)
```

But that turned to be:

```
  File "C:\....\file2.py", line 112, in attack
    app.output_text.insert(END, attack)
NameError: global name 'app' is not defined
```

I think I should relate one module with the other but I don't know how (I read about `super` function, but I don't know how to use it here). I should do something like that or create an event to pass information between Hero and Application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the class `Hero` into the `file1.py` and call the function `attack` by passing the app as another argument

Note : am not sure what enemy and damage is so am skiping that for you

```
from tkinter import * # I use python 3
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst
from file2 import *
from file2 import Hero#importing the oth

class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.output_text = tkst.ScrolledText(self, width = 100, height = 20,
                                wrap = WORD, bd=0)
        self.output_text.grid(row = 9, column = 0, columnspan = 5, sticky="nsew")

root = Tk()
root.title("Game")
app = Application(root)
center(root)

h = Hero()
h.attack(enemy, damage, app) #passing as third argument)

root.mainloop()
```

file2.py

```
class Hero(object):
    def attack(self, enemy, damage,app): #change the defenition
        Hero.hits+=1
        if self.hits==0:
            attack = "{}, attacks our enemy {}. Producing {} points of damage.\n".format(
                      self.__name, enemy.creature, truncate(damage))
            # I use code like this in the Application definition.
            app.output_text.insert(END, attack)
```

Comment: It's probably cleaner to store the reference to the application in the object itself (passing it as a parameter to `Hero()`) rather than just a single method in the class `Hero`. Presumably, other methods may need access to it as well. (That said, it's probably even better to keep GUI access and game state separate, but doing so correctly is beyond the scope of this question.)